# Google Geochart (all countries)

Tags: google-visualization

I want to put the values for every country on map but the chart has some limitations for like 6 to 7 countries. How do I create a custom chart?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there's a limit of 6-7 countries? Even the documentation you linked to has an example with 12 countries.

Comment: But that's not showing me at all more than that. Would you please correct me?

Comment: Correct what? You need to show your code.

Comment: Here is the code;

http://pastebin.com/ifwmdVTj

Comment: The code is invalid. The commas are missing between elements starting from Bhutan. (Keep the JavaScript error console open to see error messages.)

Answer (score 5):

You might find following example useful, it has a long list of countries that do map to geochart values...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages':['geochart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country',   'Value'],
["Bhutan",1],                           
["Democratic Republic of the Congo",1], 
["Liechtenstein",1],                    
["Maldives",1],                         
["Sudan",1],                            
["Zimbabwe",1],                         
["Mauritania",1],                       
["Mozambique",1],                       
["Nigeria",1],                          
["Swaziland",1],                        
["Tanzania",1],                         
["Iraq",1],                             
["Guyana",1],                           
["Namibia",1],                          
["Senegal",1],                          
["Turkmenistan",1],                     
["Afghanistan",1],                      
["Andorra",1],                          
["Fiji",1],                             
["Gabon",1],                            
["Uzbekistan",1],                       
["Cameroon",1],                         
["Cuba",1],                             
["Faroe Islands",1],                    
["El Salvador",1],                      
["Caribbean",1],                        
["Ethiopia",1],                         
["Mongolia",1],                         
["Puerto Rico",1],                      
["Samoa",1],                            
["Myanmar",1],                          
["Nicaragua",1],                        
["Seychelles",1],                       
["Tajikistan",1],                       
["Dominican Republic",1],               
["Guinea",1],                           
["Barbados",1],                         
["CI",1],                               
["Laos",1],                             
["Libya",1],                            
["Panama",1],                           
["Bahrain",1],                          
["Benin",1],                            
["Ghana",1],                            
["Haiti",1],                            
["Montenegro",1],                       
["Somalia",1],                          
["Syria",1],                            
["Ecuador",1],                          
["Honduras",1],                         
["Madagascar",1],                       
["Papua New Guinea",1],                 
["Tunisia",1],                          
["Angola",1],                           
["Botswana",1],                         
["Cyprus",1],                           
["Algeria",1],                          
["Bahamas",1],                          
["New Caledonia",1],                    
["Uganda",1],                           
["Yemen",1],                            
["Zambia",2],                           
["Antarctica",2],                       
["Paraguay",2],                         
["Jamaica",2],                          
["Palestine",2],                        
["Bolivia",2],                          
["Bosnia and Herzegovina",2],           
["Vietnam",2],                          
["Kenya",2],                            
["Luxembourg",2],                       
["Niger",2],                            
["Kuwait",2],                           
["Hawaii",2],                           
["Scotland",2],                         
["Cambodia",2],                         
["Uruguay",2],                          
["Kyrgyzstan",2],                       
["Saudi Arabia",2],                     
["Indonesia",2],                        
["Azerbaijan",2],                       
["United Arab Emirates",2],             
["Mauritius",2],                        
["Morocco",2],                          
["Albania",3],                          
["South Korea",3],                      
["Kazakhstan",3],                       
["Macedonia",3],                        
["Venezuela",3],                        
["Taiwan",3],                           
["Qatar",3],                            
["Jordan",3],                           
["Iceland",3],                          
["Guatemala",3],                        
["Costa Rica",3],                       
["Hong Kong",3],                        
["San Marino",3],                       
["Colombia",4],                         
["Moldova",4],                          
["Armenia",4],                          
["Malta",4],                            
["Nepal",5],                            
["Lebanon",5],                          
["Malaysia",5],                         
["Serbia",5],                           
["Peru",5],                             
["Trinidad and Tobago",5],              
["Lithuania",5],                        
["Estonia",6],                          
["Georgia",6],                          
["Iran",7],                             
["Chile",7],                            
["Latvia",7],                           
["Thailand",7],                         
["Egypt",7],                            
["Slovenia",8],                         
["Mexico",8],                           
["Belarus",8],                          
["Slovakia",9],                         
["Sri Lanka",9],                        
["Croatia",9],                          
["Philippines",9],                      
["Bangladesh",10],                      
["Turkey",10],                          
["Romania",13],                         
["Italy",14],                           
["South Africa",15],                    
["Hungary",15],                         
["Pakistan",16],                        
["Portugal",16],                        
["Ukraine",19],                         
["Greece",19],                          
["Oman",19],                            
["Argentina",19],                       
["Singapore",20],                       
["Bulgaria",20],                        
["Japan",25],                           
["Czech Republic ",26],                 
["Ireland",26],                         
["China",27],                           
["Finland",32],                         
["Brazil",33],                          
["Norway",34],                          
["Austria",35],                         
["Denmark",40],                         
["Belgium",41],                         
["New Zealand",42],                     
["Spain",43],                           
["Switzerland",57],                     
["Russia",62],                          
["Poland",65],                          
["Israel",73],                          
["Sweden",91],                          
["Netherlands",118],                    
["France",119],                         
["Australia",158],                      
["Canada",206],                         
["India",234],                          
["Germany",308],                        
["United Kingdom",614],                 
["United States",983],                  
["Unknown",1050],   
    ]);

    var options = {
      colorAxis: {values: [1, 10, 100, 1000], colors: ['green', '#D1E231', 'orange' ,'red'],},
      backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
      datalessRegionColor: '#999',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
   
    };
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      };
    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 600px; height: 225px;"></div>
  </body>
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: @AlirezaAsadi Indeed, what makes you think it should?

Comment: I thought if I specify "City, Country" then should be able to see on the map. I am bit dummy at this …  just starting …; I do not know what I am doing wrong!